# copying files into individual folders based on filename

Tags: file, batch-file

I need to copy multiple files from CD into individual folders based off of the filename the folders are already created.

All the filenames have an *s* as the first character.  So a filename would look like this: *s12345.pdf* and the folder it needs to be copied into is called *12345*

The next filename is *s67890.pdf* and the folder is *67890*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start. I get pretty rusty with cmd scripts when I don't use them for a while.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (*) do (
    set file=%%f
    echo move !file! !file:~1,5!\
)
```