# Use Powershell 3.0 to copy files from SharePoint source folder to multiple SharePoint folders based on filename?

Tags: pdf, sharepoint-2010, copy, powershell-3.0, windows-7-x64

**Software:**
Powershell 3.0, Windows 7, SharePoint 2010

**Task:**
Move 1000+ different pdf files from a SharePoint folder and place them into different folders based on the first 10 characters of the filename. This is all done on the same SharePoint site.

I will basically be taking data from one folder and putting them into about 10 different folders (same as the first two characters for each filename, e.g. **01**-000.001)which have multiple subfolders, e.g. **01-000.001** (each with the same name as the first 10 characters of the filenames).

**Comments:**
I am quite new at Powershell and stackoverflow (so it won't let me put more than one resource link). In SharePoint there are already named folders where the data needs to be distributed..or at least there should be one already. It would be great if I could have it put out a report at the end to tell me if everything copied over ok. I would really appreciate any input!

**Example:**
Take files named 02-001.000-Hello.pdf, 02-002.253 HelloWorld.pdf, 02-001.001HelloWorld.pdf from TEST folder and place them into subfolders inside of folder 02 with subfolders being named 02-001.000, 02-002.253, 02-001.001.

For files starting with 03 I would put them into the subfolders under the 03 folder. etc...

**Directory Structure Sample:**

```
                       where they are coming from:
```

SharePointSite URL/TEST FOLDER/*sourcefiles*

```
                        where they are going to:
```

*SharePointSite URL*/PRODUCTION FOLDERS/01/subfolders *with names same as first 10 characters of filename (first 2 characters are 01 in this case)*

*SharePointSite URL*/PRODUCTION FOLDER/02/subfolders *with names same as first 10 characters of filename (first 2 characters are 02 in this case)*

and so on...

**Resources:**
[Copy Files To Folders Based On Filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156633/copying-files-into-individual-folders-based-on-filename)

Comment: I've started looking into trying to do this locally (C drive) now with a python script and then merge the local folders with the files in them to the folders in SharePoint. I did a test and that seemed to work. It's not really the solution I wanted but it seems to be a workaround if I can get the python script finished. I may post the python code later in another forum as it may not fit here really.